# Excel Evaluate formula error

Tags: excel, formula, evaluate

My VBA code is

```
Function yEval(entry As String)
yEval = Evaluate(entry)
Application.Volatile
End Function
```

in Sheet1 in cell f4 i have formula `=yEval(Sheet2!E19)`
cell d4 on sheet1 contains number 12
Sheet2!I19 contains string $Q

> if Sheet2!e19 has string INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&12) or
>   INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&Sheet1!d4) or
>   INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&"Sheet1!D"&row()+12) the formula return
>   result from sheet pries!$Q12
>
> if Sheet2!e19 has string
>   INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&address(row(),4)) or
>   INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&"Sheet1!D"&row()) the formula return
>   result 0 it seems like ignoring the row() function

How to make work this formula to change d4 part depending on row number, if row is 5 then d5

```
INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&Sheet1!d4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem... For further insight into the issue try these from the immediate or watch window:

```
?[indirect("rc",0)]
?[index(a:a,row())]
?[offset(a1,row()-1,column()-1)]
```

Strangely they all evaluate to `A1` no matter which cell is active. It's a quirk of `Evaluate` or `[]` that references are treated relative to A1 instead of the active (calling) cell when the return value is a range reference. You can think of `row()` as equivalent to `row(RC)` in RC-notation evaluated relative to A1.

However, note that changing `]` to `&""]` in the three formulas above results in an error in the first but the expected result in the last two so that `row()` is now evaluated relative to the active cell. So it seems that Evaluate is functioning differently when the return value is not a range reference.

**Update**

Based on these observations you can use INDEX for the row reference and move INDIRECT outside:

```
Sheet1!F4:=INDIRECT(yEval(Sheet2!E19))
Sheet2!E19:"pries!"&Sheet2!I19&INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,Row())
```

...or just use RC-style references without the need for the UDF:

```
=INDIRECT("pries!"&Sheet2!I19&INDIRECT("RC4",0))
```

Comment: The problem is using ROW() or COLUMN() inside Evaluate: activesheet.evaluate("offset(a10,2,0)") works fine.

Comment: More specifically the problem is with the INDIRECT formulation since `evaluate("index(row(),1)")` works ok. Another option would therefore be to remove INDIRECT from the cell formula and use `=yeval(INDEX(yeval(Sheet2!E19),1))` instead.