# Get the cell reference of the value found by Excel INDEX function

Tags: vba, excel

### The Problem

Assume that the *active cell* contains a formula based on the `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX(myrange, x,y)
```

I would like to build a macro that locates the value found value by `INDEX` and moves the focus there, that is a *macro changing the active cell* to:

```
Range("myrange").Cells(x,y)
```

### Doing the job without macros (slow but it works)

Apart from  trivially moving the selection to `myrange` and manually counting `x` rows `y` and columns, one can:

1. Copy and paste the formula in another cell as follows:

   ```
   =CELL("address", INDEX(myrange, x,y))
   ```

   (that shows the address of the cell matched by INDEX).
2. Copy the result of the formula above.
3. Hit `F5`, `Ctrl-V`, `Enter` (paste the copied address in the `GoTo` dialog).

You are now located on the very cell found by the `INDEX` function.

Now the challenge is to automate these steps (or similar ones) with a macro.

### Tentative macros (not working)

*Tentative 1*

```
WorksheetFunction.CELL("address", ActiveCell.Formula)
```

It doesn't work since `CELL` for some reason is not part of the members of `WorksheetFunction`.

*Tentative 2*

This method involves parsing the `INDEX`-formula.

```
Sub GoToIndex()
Dim form As String, rng As String, row As String, col As String

    form = ActiveCell.Formula
    form = Split(form, "(")(1)
    rng = Split(form, ",")(0)
    row = Split(form, ",")(1)
    col = Split(Split(form, ",")(2), ")")(0)
    Range(rng).Cells(row, CInt(col)).Select

End Sub
```

This method actually works, but only for a simple case, where the main `INDEX`-formula has no nested subformulas.

### Note

Obviously in a real case `myrange`, `x` and `y`can be both simple values, such as  `=INDEX(A1:D10, 1,1)`, or  values returned from complex expressions. Typically `x`, `y` are the results of a `MATCH` function.

### EDIT

It was discovered that some solutions do not work when `myrange` is located on a sheet different from that hosting `=INDEX(myrange ...)`.

They are common practice in financial reporting, where some sheets have  the main statements whose entries are recalled from  others via an `INDEX+MATCH` formula.

Unfortunately it is just when  the found value is located on a "far" report out of sight that you need more the jump-to-the-cell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task could be done in one line much simpler than any other method:

```
Sub GoToIndex()
    Application.Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula).Select
End Sub
```

`Application.Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula)` returns a range object from which the CELL function gets properties when called from sheets.

**EDIT**
For navigating from another sheet you should first activate the target sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GoToIndex()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula)
    r.Worksheet.Activate
    r.Select
End Sub
```

Add error handling for a general case:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GoToIndex()
    Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' errors off
    Set r = Application.Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula) ' will work only if the result is a range
    On Error GoTo 0 ' errors on
    If Not (r Is Nothing) Then
        r.Worksheet.Activate
        r.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ?? With `INDIRECT` you go back to the value, while I am interested to find and move to the address. As for VBA, how do you parse the formula `=INDEX(myrange, x,y)` to get  x,y etc.?

Comment: I was too fast: for a simple `INDEX` it works, when there are subformulas (for example `x` is based on a `MATCH` function), I get: "Select methods for the Range class failed". Note that `=CELL("address", INDEX(myrange, x,y))` works also for non trivial `INDEX` functions.

Comment: I have tested with `=INDEX(A1:B2, J1+J2, J3)`, i.e. simple formulas instead of plain numbers. Will investigate why it doesn't work with match...

Comment: In my book, GoToIndex() works as expected with `=INDEX(A1:B2, J1+J2, MATCH(2, J2:J3, 0))`. Here match returns 2, J1+J2 returns 2 and after running GoToIndex() when a cell with the INDEX formula active, selection goes to B2. I have Office 2010.

Comment: Please try this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioc84i9d25l9wu8/SO_Excel_question.xlsm

Comment: Use named ranges and make `=INDEX(A1:B2, J1+J2, MATCH(2, J2:J3, 0))` like this: `=INDEX(range1, 2, MATCH(2, range2, 0))`, with the obvious meaning for `range1` and `range2`. You get the usual `5 asd` value and `GoToIndex()` keeps working. Copy this cell on another sheet. Because of named ranges, you keep getting `5 asd`, but `GoToIndex()` breaks. Using `Application.Goto ActiveCell.Formula` works slightly better, since it works if you keep the formula on the different sheet, but replace the `MATCH` with its value (2 in this case). With different sheet + calculated row/col the `.Goto` fails too.

Comment: Updated my answer and the file, it now works. If you have another edge case note that `Evaluate()` works as expected - it returns a correct object of type `Range` and any other problem should be caused by something else

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to select the cell that a formula refers to...

Assume the active cell contains: `=INDEX(myrange,x,y)`.

From the Worksheet, you could try any of these:

- Copy the formula from the formula bar and paste into the name box (to the left of the formula bar)
- Define the formula as a name, say `A`. Then type `A` into the Goto box or (name box)
- Insert hyperlink > Existing File or Web page > Address: `#INDEX(myrange,x,y)`
- Adapt the formula to make it a hyperlink: `=HYPERLINK("#INDEX(myrange,x,y)")`

Or from the VBA editor, either of these should do the trick:

- `Application.Goto Activecell.FormulaR1C1`
- `Range(Activecell.Formula).Select`

*Additional Note*:

If the cell contains a formula that refers to relative references such as `=INDEX(A:A,ROW(),1)` the last of these would need some tweaking. (Also see: [Excel Evaluate formula error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945767/excel-evaluate-formula-error)). To allow for this you could try:

```
Range(Evaluate("cell(""address""," & Mid(ActiveCell.Formula, 2) & ")")).Select
```

This problem doesn't seem to occur with R1C1 references used in `Application.Goto` or:

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "#" & mid(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1,2)
```

Comment: +1, Great VBA solutions. Named ranges (with many `INDEX`'s to debug, that is when you really need the shortcuts) clutter workbook structure. I like the hyperlink idea on a third party PC, as a fast way for when you don't have your personal WB macros handy. It worked whitout the second step, just Ctrl-K, `#INDEX(myrange,2,3)`, RET.

Comment: I was too fast: for a simple `INDEX` it works, when there are subformulas (for example `x` is based on a `MATCH` function), I get: for `Goto` method "Reference is not valid"; for `Range` method "Select methods for the Range class failed". Note that `=CELL("address", INDEX(myrange, x,y))` works also for non trivial `INDEX` functions.

Comment: and `HYPERLINK` too supports `INDEX` functions where arguments are calculated. May be this can be exploited with a macro

Comment: The errors you're encountering may be due to relative references, I've added an alternative based on your `CELL("address",INDEX())` formula.

Comment: I also updated `Application.Goto` to use `FormulaR1C1` and added a `FollowHyperlink`method.

Comment: Excel is strange beast. BTW  `...R1C1` works as is. `...FollowHyperlink` works in as far as I have previously inserted the hyperlink.  Thanks, lori_m.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MATCH() worksheet function or the VBA FIND() method.

**EDIT#1**

As you correctly pointed out, **INDEX** will return a value that may appear many times within the range, but **INDEX** will always return a value from some fixed spot, say

```
=INDEX(A1:K100,3,7)
```

will always give the value in cell **G3**  so the address is "builtin" to the formula

If, however, we have something like:

```
=INDEX(A1:K100,Z100,Z101)
```

Then we would require a macro to parse the formula and evaluate the arguments.

Comment: What do you mean? finding/matching the value of `INDEX(myrange, x,y)` in `myrange`? If this value is, say, 1, there can be hundreds of 1's in `myrange`. How do I know which one is the `x,y` value?

Comment: yes, and in fact my question is just about seeking help in writing this macro.

Answer (score 0):

Both @lori_m and @V.B. gave brilliant solutions in their own way almost in parallel. 
Very difficult for me to choose the closing answer, but V.B. even created Dropbox test file, so...

Here I just steal the best from parts from them.

```
'Move to cell found by Index()
Sub GoToIndex()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.Goto ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 ' will work only if the result is a range
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Active cell does not evaluate to a range")
End Sub
```

I associated this "jump" macro with CTRL-j and  it works like a charm.

If you use balance sheet like worksheets (where `INDEX`-formulas, selecting entries from other sheets, are very common), I really suggest you to try it.